# Como calcular a idade de uma pessoa no Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso de uma comando sql que retorne a idade da pessoa.
Tenho a data de nascimento da pessoa no banco, preciso calcular sua idade pelo SQL.

Comment: Cara não entendi como você quer exatamente. Favor explicar mais

Comment: Tenho a data de nascimento da pessoa no banco, preciso calcular sua idade pelo SQL,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Faço

```
NVL(Floor(Months_Between(DtCalc,DtNasc)/12),0)
```

é uma solução

na realidade uso uma function para isto.

Comment: Motta, pode continuar a responder a minha pergunta anterior, sobre sequencia de resultados

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/294163/tempo-corrido-calculo-de-datas esta ? saco quase nada de php , mas em geral a melhor forma de trabalhar com tempo é reduzir tudo para a unidade mais baixa (segudos , milissegudos etc) operar os claculos e reconverter para a unidade em questão

Answer (score -2):

```
rslt = (diferenca.days / 365.25)
#ano_atual-ano

if (dia == dia_atual and mes == mes_atual):
    print ("O %s tem %d anos!" %(nome, rslt))
else:
    ((dia > dia_atual and mes == mes_atual) or mes < mes_atual)
    print ("O %s tem %d anos!" %(nome, rslt))****
```